# Edittext previous value

Tags: java, android

I have a edit text with value 1 and then I change it to 10 and press a button.I want to store the value 1 in a variable and 10 in a separate variable.How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use editText method addTextChangedListener

```
     editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

implements TextChangeListener

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
         prev_value = s.toString().trim(); // will print 1
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       latest_value = s.toString().trim(); // will print 10
   }
});
```

Comment: this works fine if previous vale is 1 digit this doesn't work when the first value is 1 after I change it to 10 and if I delete 0 in 10 and type 15 only 1 is stored as the prev value but I want 10 to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You can get `input` values by adding `addTextChangedListener` to your `editText`.

**2.** Instead of using `varibale` you can use `ArrayList<String>` to store `old` and `new` input values and use it later as per your needs.

**Here is an example:**

```
    final ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            values.add(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });


    // Use values
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        String value = values.get(i);

        // Do something with value
    }
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: If I use this function only 1 digit of the previous number is getting stored.For ex:When the first number is 15 I erase 5 and type 10,1 is stored as the previous value.

Comment: suppose: user input>> 123 then erase 3 and input 45, again erase 45 and input 9. so the stings are 123 >> 1245 >> 129... Which values you want to store as old and new?

Comment: For the above example: array list values are as below>> 1, 12, 123, 12, 124, 1245, 124, 12, 129